# What's the difference between 'suggest' and 'recommends' package in apt terminology?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

```
root@xxx:~# aptitude show gcc
Package: gcc
New: yes
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 45.1 k
Depends: cpp (>= 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1), gcc-5 (>= 5.2.1-12~)
Recommends: libc6-dev | libc-dev
Suggests: gcc-multilib, make, manpages-dev, autoconf, automake, libtool, flex, bison, gdb, gcc-doc
Conflicts: gcc-doc (< 1:2.95.3)
Provides: c-compiler
Description: GNU C compiler
```

There is an option for 'apt-get' which is --install-suggest, and there are also an option -r (--with-recommends) for aptitude, Are those two the some thing?